# Copy file and rename file on destination

Tags: java

I created a java function to copy `file_1` from `path_1` to `path_2`.

Function code is:

```
public void copyFiles(String source, String destination) {

    File src = new File(source);
    File dest = new File(destination);
    try {
        Files.copy(src.toPath(), dest.toPath());
    }catch (IOException e){
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException.", e);

    }
}
```

I would like to modifiy my function to copy `file_1` from `path_1` and rename the file on destination to `file_dest`
The idea of the function is to be used in another function.
How can do it please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you search is renameTo which is documented here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

In your case it would look like:

```
dest.renameTo(newFile)
```

And watch out: "newFile" is not just the filename, but an File Object. For further information you can read the provided documentation.